# Secure firebase webhook

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, webhooks, typeform

I have to create a webhook from typeform to firebase. I will create a cloud function listening to events sent from typeform. The typeform is managed by a third party.

The only issue I have, is the authorization part for the webhook. I understood (from reading different post) that anyone can "talk" to the cloud function URL. But I would like to have a secure and exclusive communication between typeform and firebase.

Any hints ?

Thank for your time.

Comment: You might want to have a look here and see if it helps: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

Answer (score 3):

You can definitively connect a Typeform webhook to a Cloud function and push data to Firebase storage.

In addition to authentication pointed by Frank, Typeform also provides a signature mechanism to ensure that the request comes from Typeform webhook.

Typeform lets you define a secret to sign the webhook payload.

When you receive the payload on your end, in the cloud function, you verify first if it's signed correctly, if it's not it means it's not coming from Typeform, therefore, you should not deal with it.

Here is an example to verify the webhook signature:

```js
app.post('/typeform/webhook', async (request, response) => {
  console.log('~> webhook received');
  // security check, let's make sure request comes from typeform
  const signature = request.headers['typeform-signature']
  const isValid = verifySignature(signature, request.body.toString())
  if (!isValid) {
    throw new Error('Webhook signature is not valid, someone is faking this!');  
  }
      
  //valid signature let's do something with data received
})
```

And here is the `verifySignature` function

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
const verifySignature = function(receivedSignature, payload){
  const hash = crypto
            .createHmac('sha256', webhookSecret)
            .update(payload)
            .digest('base64')
  return receivedSignature === `sha256=${hash}`
}
```

There are more details on [Typeform documentation](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/secure-your-webhooks/).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I implemented your solution, I'm still a bit scared that the secret could leak since the third party will probably manage the typeform. But otherwise, it seems to be the unique way of doing it. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Glat it worked :)
In the typeform settings, no one can see the secret, it's only shown once at creation time.
the only option available is to generate a new one. Make it clear that they should not touch that field otherwise they will break your webhook handler.

Comment: It seems there are some inconsistencies in the documentation and what are in the settings panel. In the documentation they say: the secret can only be set through their API. But I can access it from the admin panel. And they added a "show" button in the secret input, thus letting anyone to see what the secret is. We will try to keep the typeform on our side.

Comment: What about the anyone can "talk" to the cloud function URL? If an attacker gets the URL, the function can be triggered many many times and increase the bill.

Comment: @AlitonOliveira that's a general comment valid for all type of cloud function.
In this particular case, it's recommended to add a security layer by signing the webhook payload coming from Typeform, and by verifying this signature as soon as the endpoint is called. Like this, you can make sure it's actually Typeform calling you.
All the requests coming from the attacker will likely fail quickly, and you won't be charged much for each execution.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `request.body.toString()` does not work the way it is described in @Nicolas Greniés answer. The result will always be the string `"[Object object]"`, as it only utilizes the default prototype as described here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

A valid approach to stringify `req.body` would be to use `JSON.stringify()` which would still not deliver the expected result as **you need to hash the original binary data** (https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/secure-your-webhooks/).

#### The Solution (without Firebase)

Use `app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }))` as specified here ([Validate TypeForm Webhook payload in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149652/validate-typeform-webhook-payload-in-node)) to get the raw binary data and pass the request body directly into the hashing function.

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: "application/json" })); // Notice .raw !

app.post("/typeform-handler", (req, res) => {
      const hash = crypto
            .createHmac('sha256', MY_TYPEFORM_SECRET)
            .update(req.body) // Pass the raw body after getting it using bodyParser
            .digest('base64')
})
```

#### The solution using Firebase

If you are using a Firebase Cloud Function to handle the request, you can't use `bodyParser` this way as Firebase already takes care of the parsing (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request). Instead, use `req.rawBody` to access the raw body and pass it to the hash function.

```js
// No need for bodyParser

app.post("/typeform-handler", (req, res) => {
      const hash = crypto
            .createHmac('sha256', MY_TYPEFORM_SECRET)
            .update(req.rawBody) // Notice .rawBody instead of just .body
            .digest('base64')
})
```

**Remark for TypeScript users**

The default Express `Request` object does not contain a `rawBody` property. Be aware that TypeScript therefore might throw an error of `no overload matches this call` or `Property 'rawBody' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'`. The actual `Request` object will however be provided by Firebase and will contain said properties. You can access the actual `Request` object type using `functions.https.Request`.